# Error al llamar al método de un controlador en script luego de publicar proyecto

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, iis

Buenas, tengo un proyecto para guardar formularios que cuando lo corro en localhost, con el IIS expres de visual studio 2015, me funciona todo correctamente, pero al realizar el "publish" y quiero guardar un informe, me aparece un error en el siguiente lugar: 
[image: Captura]

El error es específicamente en la llamada al méotodo "SaveOrder" del controlador "Home".

[image: Error al hacer el POST]

Una vez publicado, funciona todo, excepto eso, la funcionalidad más imporante y en desarrollo, éste problema no aparece. Ayuda!  Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Cuando quiero guardar, va directamente al "error: function()..."

Comment: es un proyecto asp.net clasico o es asp.net mvc ? porque veo que la url que invocas no lleva un aspx, pero en loa tag has puesto asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria que en la definicion de error muestres el problema que se esta generando

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Tambien podrias acceder al `Developer Tools` del browser (al cual accedes con F12) y en la solapa network analizar como responde la invocacion al servicio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si usas IE accedes a la sola `Red (network)` alli podras ver el detalle que informa acerca de la incocacion al servidor

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, por suerte, lo pude solucionar cambiando el path Home/SaveOrder por un @Url.Action. . Saludos!

Comment: ahh ok entonces era la url que defines, es recomendable usar Url.Action, pero igual la forma en que lo hacias no lo veo incorrecto, por ahi me genera ruido el "/" del principio

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en que, publicado el proyecto, no llamará al controlador correctamente. La solución es usar `@Url.Action("Metodo","Controlador")`.

Para llamarlo desde con AJAX seria así:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveOrder", "Home")',
        ...
```

Comment: sí, ese fue el problema. Muchas gracias por responder. Saludos